# What is wrong with this Jquery function, help

Tags: jquery, function, with-statement

```
$(function() {
    $("table.section thead").click(function() {
      if ($(this).next("table.section tbody").style.display == "block"){
         $(this).next("table.section tbody").slideUp("slow");
      }
      if ($(this).next("table.section tbody").style.display == "none"){
         $(this).next("table.section tbody").slideDown("slow");
      }
    });
});
```

I dont know how to achieve this, any help would be very much appreciated.

UPDATE:

I was trying to use the following function.

```
$(function() {
    $("table.section thead").click(function() {
    $(this).next("table.section tbody").slideToggle("slow");

    });
});
```

Which it giving me a problem, (when thead it collapse and you click on it, it expands and then collapse again, so it would always be collapse). That is why I am trying to get the function at the top.

Comment: I want to a click event to all "table.section thead" so when its click hides the tbody of the table.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use the visible selector in this case:

```
$(function() {
    $("table.section thead").click(function() {
      var body = $(this).next("table.section tbody");
      if (body.is(":visible"))
         body.slideUp("slow");
      else
         body.slideDown("slow");
    });
});
```

But probably much simpler just use [`.slideToggle()`](http://api.jquery.com/slideToggle/) like this:

```
$(function() {
    $("table.section thead").click(function() {
      $(this).next("table.section tbody").slideToggle("slow");
    });
});
```

Comment: Agreed on `slideToggle()`, this makes things **a lot** simpler.

Comment: @Nick: Thanks, that is What I was looking for, but the problem I am getting with the simpler function, stills happend, when the tbody its not visible it expands and collapses with the same click, and I tried to use return false, Do you know why this may be? Thanks.

Comment: I added an alert in the if statement and another on else, and it always gets to the if so it does slideUP all the time.

Comment: @Cesar - Sounds like you're attaching the event twice, are you running or including the function 2 times?

Comment: its a very big form, but I cant not see the function or anything similar any other place.

Comment: If the tbody only have one row it works, but if it has more than one it does that strange thing. Any Ideas?